# <form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="GET"> has to redirect to the website when I type a URL in the input field

Tags: forms, google-search

I have a simple search input box in my webpage that has google search action to it.This is the code.

```
<div className="search-container">
        <form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="GET">
          <input type="search" id="search" name="q" placeholder="Search Google or type URL" />
          <button className="icon" type="submit"><i className="small material-icons">search</i></button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

[This is the image of search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2AZH.png)

So if i type anything for example like apple, it searches google for apple and displays the content. But if I type a url like http://facebook.com, it again searches google and displays the search result for facebook.

But I need it to redirect to that particular website when I enter a url. If i enter http://facebook.com and press enter, It must redirect me to the facebook website and not to the google search results page for facebook.

Please help me out in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to use js for that

Comment: can you please explain me how to do that. @Pavitra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively what you want here is for the one button to do two different things (search via google, or redirect to a URL). Because you want one element to do two different things, I would recommend using Javascript so that the page can decide which thing to do.

The following code will take in a string from an input box and either redirect if it starts with "HTTP://" or searches google if it doesn't:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function search(query){
                if(query.slice(0, 7) == "http://"){
                    window.location.href = query
                }
                else{
                    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="url">Enter a URL or search query</label>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
        <button type="submit" onclick="search(document.getElementById('search').value)">search</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add JS to check whether the input value is a URL.

```js
function go() {
  const val = document.getElementById('input').value
  window.open(
    (isURL(val) ? '' :
      'https://google.com/search?q=') + val,
    '_blank')
}

function isURL(url) {
  try {
    new URL(url)
    return true
  } catch (e) {
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Search Google or type URL" />
<button onclick="go()">Search</button>
```